# Relative Dates in MacOS Mail app

Tags: macos, mail.app

I would like to stop the display of relative dates in the MacOS Mail app. I know how to stop the display of relative dates in Finder. I have not seen any information for carrying that preference to any other apps, whether intrinsic Apple apps or third-party apps. Any hints how this can be done?